# How to call didFinishLaunchingWithOptions after some delay

Tags: iphone

I am parsing using SOAP, in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, only for the first time app gets launch.
The issue is, my view gets called before the xml is parsed using

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

My didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:...................

//everything here with SOAP

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES; }
```

I want to call this

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

once my

```
> -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

gets finished and I get the result string.

Currently, I got the result string after sometime, in the next view.
I just want to call the next view, once I got the result string.

How can I get that?

Comment: It seems you want to turn an async operation into a synchronic one.

Comment: I think this is not a good option as watchdog timer may time out.

Comment: Than how can i perform this action,what is the most suitable way?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're choosing the wrong approach. Apple requires apps to startup within 5 seconds give or take. If your parsing would have issues (because of bad network connection e.g.) then your app will just close before it's finished parsing and your view controller will never be displayed.

You should put the XMLParsing code in a seperate class and perform a callback on the AppDelegate once parsing is finished. Then set the results of the parsing as a property of your view controller and update interface if required (e.g. by calling '-reloadData' on a tableView).

Comment: What exactly i want is, i want to call the viewdidload or viewwill appear, once my parsing is finished. I can put the condition, if i got the result, i'll move to my next view, else , i can show an alert.But my main intention is just to open the view, once parsing is done. how can i doo that?